# Illegal string offset trying to override WordPress comment form fields

Tags: php, wordpress

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. My code looks exactly like [this guy's](http://chipcullen.com/altering-the-comment-form-in-wordpress/) (method 2, toward the bottom), but it's not working. Here's my code:

```
/** Change comment form title **/
function change_comment_fields($fields) {
    if (isset($fields)) {
        $fields["title_reply"] = "Leave a Comment";
        var_dump($fields);
    }
    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'comment_form_default_fields', 'change_comment_fields' );
add_filter( 'comment_form_field_comment', 'change_comment_fields' );
```

Which var_dumps:

```
array(4) {
  ["author"]=>
     string(207) "<p class="comment-form-author"><label for="author">Name <span class="required">*</span></label> <input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="" size="30" aria-required='true' required='required' /></p>"
  ["email"]=>
     string(235) "<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">Email <span class="required">*</span></label> <input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="" size="30" aria-describedby="email-notes" aria-required='true' required='required' /></p>"
  ["url"]=>
     string(125) "<p class="comment-form-url"><label for="url">Website</label> <input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="" size="30" /></p>"
  ["title_reply"]=>
     string(15) "Leave a Comment"
}
```

So it seems as though the array is being changed properly. "Leave a Reply" doesn't change, but if I set 'url' instead of 'title_field', the URL box will change to "Leave a Comment".

Nevertheless, PHP still spits out this:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'title_reply' in /home/<name>/public_html/<site>/wp-content/themes/baskerville-child/functions.php on line 14
string(113) "Lp class="comment-form-comment">
```

(Where line 14 corresponds to the where I'm setting $fields["title_reply"].)

Any ideas? (You can view a sample page [here](http://tastytechtips.com/maintenance/2015/06/spring-cleaning-with-ccleaner).)

Comment: is the function being called twice with your two filters? Generally you will get that warning if you try and use a non numeric array key on a string (i.e. if `$fields` was a string e.g. `false` instead of a array). You can clear the error by testing if you have passed a array (and you can debug the function this way by var_dump and exit if not a array)

Comment: The error message means that `$fields` is not an array (at that time when the error occurs), but a string. And the debug output shown after the error message confirms that. So consult the filter documentation, and see what kind of parameter is passed to the filter function for each of those two. Either that differs in general, or it might depend on how many fields the form you are trying to manipulate actually has (one vs multiple.)

Comment: Aha, it seems I didn't realize what the filter `comment_form_field_comment` does. I was under the misconception that it was to filter the comment form for a visitor who wasn't signed in. Turns out it's for filtering the comment textarea text, so yeah, it was passing a string. I thought since the var_dump was printing two copies of the array (I only included one) that both calls were receiving the same data. But upon closer inspection I discovered that the data wasn't a duplicate (one was fields, the other labels), and that both var_dumps were as a result of applying the first filter. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So it seems I didn't realize what the filter `comment_form_field_comment` does. I was under the misconception that it was to filter the comment form for a visitor who wasn't signed in. Turns out it's for filtering the comment textarea text, so yeah, it was passing a string. I thought since the var_dump was printing two copies of the array (I only included one) that both calls were receiving the same data. But upon closer inspection I discovered that the data wasn't a duplicate (one was fields, the other labels), and that both var_dumps were as a result of applying the first filter.

Also, I the first (non-warning-producing) filter was wrong as well. To change the title, I needed to use `comment_form_defaults`.